# git - is there a reference to upstream branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, upstream-branch

I can ask for differences since I started on a feature branch:

```
git diff upstream-branch...
```

But it requires that I know what the upstream branch is. Is there a reference for the upstream branch, whatever it may be without me knowing before hand or having to dig for it? Like, I don't know:

```
git diff UPSTREAM...
```

Comment: Not reading [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltbranchnamegtupstreamemegemmasterupstreamememuem), yeah? :-(

Comment: i am not willing to read every git doc out there... only as needed. And checking answers here in SO provide the answer to at least most everyday questions.... this one I think hadn't been asked before, I might be wrong, for sure, but google didn't point to anything right away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a one liner: `git diff @{u}...`

---

The upstream of a branch is composed of two parts, both of which can be set and retrieved with `git config`.  The *remote* part is easy, as given a branch named *`B`*, it's `branch.B.remote`.  The second half is much harder if you use `git config`.<sup>1</sup>  Fortunately, since about Git version 1.8 or so, the `@{upstream}` suffix works for all things that parse branch names:

```
foo@{upstream}
```

is the upstream of branch `foo`.  `@{u}` is shorthand for `@{upstream}`, and standalone, means `HEAD@{upstream}`.

To get the *symbolic name* of the upstream, if that's what you need, use `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name` or `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref`.  Note that if there is no upstream set for the current or given branch, you'll get an error from `git rev-parse`.

---

<sup>1</sup>It's `branch.B.merge`, but this must be run through the `fetch =` mappings for the given remote to find the right remote-tracking name.  That is, suppose that branch `br` has `branch.br.remote = r` and `branch.br.merge = xyz`.  You must then run `refs/heads/xyz` through the `remote.r.fetch` rules to come up with the remote-tracking name corresponding to `xyz` on remote `r`.  There's no command-line command that will do this for you.

Comment: Wow.... @torek. Can I somehow give you, i don't know.... 50 points?

Comment: @eftshift0: there are various ways to use rep points. I've never investigated them myself, and I don't really *need* any more at this point in time. :-)